Is it possible to let Alt-F4 cycle through programs on other workspaces too?
I am on Xubuntu 22.04.
Before shutting down a computer, it is best practice to close all open windows first. Alt-F4 closes the window which has the program focus (and if there is still something to save, a prompt usually appears).
If you have program windows open on several workspaces, you can use Alt-F4 several times to clear all the program windows on the current workspace only. One more press of Alt-F4 opens the dialog box with which you decide to shut down the computer - even if there are still program windows on another workspace that may still have unsaved data.
I want Alt-F4 to also cycle through the open windows on other workspaces automatically, if there are program windows open on any of them.
How to achieve this goal?
